# Is there a possibility to monitor https sites in nagios over a proxy?

Tags: proxy, https, openssl, nagios

i have a little question about the nagios tool:

Is there a possibility to monitor https sites in nagios over a proxy? Which means i want to monitor whether my proxy can reach some https ressources in the internet? I think it would be no problem with this command:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -j CONNECT -u "https://banking.postbank.de" -S
```

But our nagios server has no direct internet access and this command doesnt work.. (openssl is installed) I think the "-S" option doesnt work with proxy..:

```
  /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -I 10.46.4.200 -p 8080 -j CONNECT -u "https://banking.postbank.de" -S
```

So here is the question: What to do? Is der some kind of check_https ? or something like that? Has anybody done a check like that?

Thank you very much for help,
Fake4d

Answer (score 9, accepted):

script it! write your own plugin using [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)

eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -t 5 --timeout 30 -O /dev/null -o /dev/null -e https_proxy=your.proxy:port https://www.google.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
  echo all ok
  exit 0
else
  echo not ok
  exit 2
fi
```

you can obviously extend it eg to check the content of returned page.

Comment: Hello - this worked fine for me - i use it in this syntax:

`wget -t 5 --timeout 30 -e https_proxy=10.2.33.54:3128 https://example.com  --no-check-certificate`

Answer (score 2):

check_http certainly works for https websites, and '-j CONNECT' is essential as you already have but you will also need a -H .. And your proxy server is setup to pass-through https

example:

`check_http -I PROXYHOST -p PROXYPORT -H FQDN -u RELATIVE-URI -S -j CONNECT -s STRING-TO-MATCH`

- I have had better results using relative uri rather than the full url .. eg: '/vendors' instead of 'http://example.com/vendors'
- Of course the -s is only if you are trying to match a particular string in the returned content
- Finally, there are environments in which your best bet would still be to wrap wget or curl in a script

Answer (score 2):

Small enhancement of pQd's answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL=$1
RESPONSE_CODE=${2:-200}
TIMEOUT=${3:-10}

case $RESPONSE_CODE in
401)
  EXPECTED_RETURN_CODE=6
  ;;
200)
  EXPECTED_RETURN_CODE=0
  ;;
*)
  EXPECTED_RETURN_CODE=0
  ;;
esac


start=`date +%s`
wget -t 1 --timeout ${TIMEOUT} -O /dev/null -o /dev/null  -e http_proxy=PUTYOURPROXYHERE:8080 ${URL}
WGET_RETURN_CODE=$?
end=`date +%s`

PERFDATA="time=$(expr ${end} - ${start})s"

if [ ${WGET_RETURN_CODE} -eq ${EXPECTED_RETURN_CODE} ] ; then
  echo "HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 ${RESPONSE_CODE} OK for ${URL}|${PERFDATA}"
  exit 0
else
  echo "HTTP CRITICAL: Did not receive HTTP/1.1 ${RESPONSE_CODE} for ${URL}|${PERFDATA}"
  exit 2
fi
```

Change the proxy server and call it like this:

```
$ bash check_http_proxy.sh https://stackoverflow.com/ 200 3
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK for https://stackoverflow.com/|time=1s
or
$ bash check_http_proxy.sh http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/authenticatedimage/default.aspx 401 10
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 401 OK for http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/authenticatedimage/default.aspx|time=0s
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently had the same problem so I wrapped the wget approach into a Nagios plugin https://github.com/SimpleFinance/nagios-check-http-proxy

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.